# How can I remove a component using the children prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to achieve this scenario:

1. I have **Foo component** with **bar prop**
2. If bar prop is **true** --> **mount Bar component** that is inside the Foo component
3. if bar prop is **false** --> **unmount Bar component**
4. **I don't want Example component to be aware of this show/hide, I want only Foo to know when to show or hide it**
5. Bar is not necessary a direct child of Foo, it can also be nested deeper in the children of Foo

> ```
> const Example = () => {
>   return (
>     <Foo bar={true/false}>
>       <div>some div</div>
>       <Bar></Bar>
>     </Foo>
>   )
> };
>
> class Foo extends React.Component {
>
>   componentWillReceiveProps({bar}) {
>     if (bar) {
>       /* I want to show bar!! */
>     } else {
>       /* I want to remove only bar!! */
>       /* maybe doing something like: this.props.children.searchForBar().removeNode() */
>     }
>   }
>
>   render () {
>     return (
>       <div>{this.props.children}</div>
>     )
>   }
> };
>
> const Bar = () => 'I am some bar';
> ```

I've tried to manipulate this.props.children but React blocked me from modifying children myself.

Do I need maybe an outer service for communication between these 2 components ?

Should I use context maybe ?

Looking for an advice on how to approach this issue.

Comment: Yes, you would need something from the outside to handle the state (like redux) if you want to toggle <Bar> even though <Bar> is not a child of <Foo>

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is to use `Bar component` inside of the `Foo component` and render that based on a `ternary condition`.

Also return a JSX element(Valid react element from Bar component) rather than a string.

```js
const Example = () => {
  return (
    <Foo bar={true}>
      <div>some div</div>
    </Foo>
   
  )
};

class Foo extends React.Component {

  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        {this.props.bar? <Bar />: null}
      </div>
    )
  }
};

const Bar = () => <div>I am some bar</div>;

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I am trying to nest Bar outside of Foo. I am basically trying to understand how can a component have 'sub component' that it can be aware of. so Foo is the main component but it can 'control' sub-component like Bar and hide it even though Bar is not inside of Foo

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to use some kind of message bus or pubSub. In that kind of approach, Bar component would have to subscribe to the bus, and show/hide itself. Foo component would publish appriopriate messages in componentWillReceiveProps. More: [here](https://www.ctheu.com/2015/02/12/how-to-communicate-between-react-components/)